# Tomcat 7 not reading web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, cpanel

I've a Struts 2 based web application. It's completely running on my local network. But while I deployed on `cpanel` its not running.

**Problem:** `Tomcat 7` not reading `web.xml` file in `cpanel`.

if I invoke my url `www.abc.com` the `index.jsp` is displaying as home page. Actually I set `home.jsp` as home page to my application.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If I click on home link in `index.jsp` (contains menu) then it displays error as

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.action was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I didn't understand whats the problem here. Previously I've Struts 1 based web application on the same domain `www.abc.com`. Its working fine. I didn't change any configurations just I deleted all the Struts 1 related files and folders and deployed my new Struts 2 based application. So in `index.jsp` file `html` based content is displaying.

If I print `<%out.println("welcome");%>` in `index.jsp` it prints `welcome`. So `java` working.

If I invoke like `www.abc.com/wp-admin` also I'm getting the above `404` error. Any suggestions please. If any extra information you need I will provide it.

**struts.xml:**

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="30000000"/>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
<action name="index" class="com.myapp.ysrcptv.HomeAction">
    <result>index.jsp</result>
</action>
---------------
```

**Key points:** java is working. Struts 1 based application is running. But Struts 2 based application is not running.

Comment: So, S1 means "Struts 1", and S2 means "Struts 2"? Why not use "Struts 1" and "Struts 2" to make that clear?

Comment: thanks @ JB Nizet. Is there any way to convert my application from struts 2 to struts 1 easily. Since struts 1 based application is running. So if i convert from struts 2 to struts 1 may it works.